# Re-rendring pdf issues when i update page data

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

i am using React-pdf/renderer to render Recipe PDFs, varying on which invoice the user wants to view. On the first pdf view it works, however after closing the dialog window and attempting to view the same PDF or another, it displays previous data on pdf.

here is my pdf function,

```
const ItemPdf = () => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page
        style={{ ...styles.main, padding: "20px 20px 20px 30px" }}
        size="A4"
      >
        <View
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
          }}
        >
          <View>
            <ReactTextPdf
              style={{
                marginBottom: "10px",
                fontFamily: "ProximaNova-Bold",
              }}
            >
              {itemDetails?.name ? <Text>{itemDetails.name}</Text> : null}
            </ReactTextPdf>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "flex-start",
              marginTop: "10px",
            }}
          >
            <Image
              src={itemDetails?.image ? itemDetails.image : HouseWhisk}
              style={{
                width: "80px",
                height: "80px",
                objectFit: "cover",
                borderRadius: "10px",
              }}
            />
            <ReactTextPdf
              style={{
                ...styles.textStyle,
                width: "200px",
                fontSize: "10px",
                paddingLeft: "10px",
              }}
            >
              {ReactHtmlParser(itemDetails?.intro)}
            </ReactTextPdf>
            <View style={styles.tableRow}>
              <View
                style={{
                  ...styles.notesCol,
                  marginLeft: "5px",
                  paddingTop: "2px",
                }}
              >
                <ReactTextPdf
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "11px",
                    fontFamily: "ProximaNova-Bold",
                  }}
                >
                  Serving size
                </ReactTextPdf>
                <ReactTextPdf
                  style={{ ...styles.textFonts, paddingTop: "5px" }}
                >
                  {itemDetails?.serving_size}
                  {itemDetails?.serving_size_descriptor?.name}
                </ReactTextPdf>
              </View>

              <View
                style={{
                  ...styles.notesCol,
                  marginLeft: "10px",
                  paddingTop: "2px",
                }}
              >
                <ReactTextPdf
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "11px",
                    fontFamily: "ProximaNova-Bold",
                  }}
                >
                  Yield amount
                </ReactTextPdf>
                <ReactTextPdf
                  style={{ ...styles.textFonts, paddingTop: "5px" }}
                >
                  {itemDetails?.yield_amount}
                  {itemDetails?.yield_descriptor?.name}
                </ReactTextPdf>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  ...styles.notesCol,
                  marginLeft: "10px",
                  paddingTop: "2px",
                }}
              >
                <ReactTextPdf
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "11px",
                    fontFamily: "ProximaNova-Bold",
                  }}
                >
                  Your price
                </ReactTextPdf>
                <ReactTextPdf
                  style={{ ...styles.textFonts, paddingTop: "5px" }}
                >
                  ${itemDetails.suggested_price}
                </ReactTextPdf>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <ReactTextPdf
              style={{
                fontSize: "16px",
                padding: "12px 0 15px 0",
                fontFamily: "ProximaNova-Bold",
              }}
            >
              Ingredients
            </ReactTextPdf>
            {console.log("ingredientHeaderList", ingredientHeaderList)}
            {ingredientHeaderList.map((item: any, index: number) => {
              return (
                <View key={index}>
                  <ReactTextPdf
                    style={{ fontSize: "12px", paddingBottom: "7px" }}
                  >
                    {item.name}:
                  </ReactTextPdf>
                  {item.data.map((itemData: any, itemIndex: number) => (
                    <View key={`rin-${itemIndex}`}>
                      <ReactTextPdf
                        style={{
                          fontSize: "10px",
                          paddingBottom: "9px",
                        }}
                      >
                        {itemData.amount || 1}
                        {itemData.unit}
                        {itemData.name}
                        {itemData.ingredient_note}
                      </ReactTextPdf>
                    </View>
                  ))}
                </View>
              );
            })}
          </View>
          {getHtml("Method", itemDetails.method)}
          {getHtml("Preparation options", itemDetails.prep)}
          {getHtml("Chef's notes", itemDetails.notes)}
          {getHtml("Packaging instructions", itemDetails.packaging_notes)}
          {getHtml("Customer care instructions", itemDetails.customer_notes)}
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};
```

here is the button for downloading pdf

```
<PDFDownloadLink
  style={{
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }}
  document={<ItemPdf />}
  fileName={`${itemDetails.name}(${dayjs(
    itemDetails?.delivery_start_datetime?.replace(/-/g, "/")
  ).format("MMM DD, YYYY")}).pdf`}
>
  Print
</PDFDownloadLink>;
```